# Advices for sending email in Django app from Vagrant box

Tags: django, vagrant, postfix-mta

I'm new to Vagrant and I'm building my website using Django, really cool but now I need to send emails from my vagrant box (Ubuntu) and I'll be using the Django function `send_mail()`.

I'm not sure how to proceed, I guess I'll need to install the postfix cookbook, probably check that there are no issues with the ports, and it should be ok?

If you could just give me some tips, what's best, recommended, the easiest way, I would greatly appreciate it!

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django had an email backend that outputs the email to the console. Add this to your settings:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
```

Also you can run a python SMTP server with:

```
python -m smtpd -n -c DebuggingServer localhost:1025
```

Please, check this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#testing-email-sending

Comment: It works great just by changing the backend, thanks! It is good for development and for now and the stage I am. But if I want to check it sends correctly and the result in different email clients, meaning if I want to test some HTML email, I'd like to have it work and be sent from my dev environment and my vagrant box. Any idea how to do so?

Comment: OK, in this case you can configure Django to use gmail http://www.daveperrett.com/articles/2009/10/16/sending-django-email-with-gmail/